# OR-Tools: Limit combinations against given range

Tags: java, constraint-programming, or-tools

I am creating a simple solver application. You can check the code below.

Now I want to limit the combination created as solutions to a certain number. (eg: 1000 max). Since the solver uses step value of 1 as default. inputting `2` for `numberOfItems` result in 101. but if i make `numberOfItems` to `3` total solutions will be above 5000 and if `numberOfItems` is `4` total solutions will be above 10000.

How to build a solver that will be able to change the step value according to the inputs. Without compromising on the distribution.

```
int totalCumilation = 100; //adding values of all item should equal to this. User might give 100 to 100000 
int numberOfItems = 3; //User might give 2..25

Solver solver = new Solver("MY_CP");

IntVar[] weights = solver.makeIntVarArray(numberOfItems, 0, totalCumilation, "weights");

solver.addConstraint(solver.makeEquality(solver.makeSum(weights), totalCumilation));

DecisionBuilder decisionBuilder = solver.makeDefaultPhase(weights);
solver.solve(decisionBuilder);

while (solver.nextSolution()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(weights[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");

}

System.out.println("Finished");
```

***I have some more constraints which i have note shared in the code. Once best solutions are propagated (eg 1000 items). I will will be exploring (zooming) for some more solutions (After applicaing those constrains 5000 generated items might become 3000, and we will be only showing 1000 of them).***

Comment: Does this answer your question ?
https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_tasks#solution-limits
Otherwise it's "Look  Good To Me" that combinatory explode when increasing the number of items....

Comment: @Mizux but it i limit the solution to 1000, it will just show the first 1000 solutions, not evenly distributed.

Comment: There is no support in or-tools to build evenly distributed solution. Even random search do not have those guaranties. I would implement your recursive schema. Generate > 1k solutions, select a subset that maximize diversity, then zoom in and so on. Most of the work is on the statistical part, not on OR-Tools IMO. Hope this helps.

Comment: @LaurentPerron thanks for a defenite answer